# Javascript variable that always returns value of function

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this (and that it is no), but is it possible to create a variable that always returns the value of a function without "calling" the variable?

I'm sick of an inactivity warning on a website I use.  I look at it a few times a day, but I keep it open in case there's an update I need to look at.  It automatically signs me out after 15 minutes using some javascript--the token isn't invalidated by a cookie expiring, nor is my session removed server-side--and the variable it checks is called `last_user_action`.

I'd like to make `last_user_action` always point to `new Date().getTime();`.

```
last_user_action = function() { new Date().getTime(); }
```

would work if I could easily change all the references to `last_user_action` to instead be`last_user_action()`, but I can't.

```
last_user_action = (function() { return new Date().getTime(); })();
```

only sets the value once.

So like I said, I doubt there's a way to do this, but if it is possible, how would I do it?

**EDIT**
It occurs to me now, it'd be easier to just run

```
window.setInterval(function() { last_user_action = new Date().getTime(); }, 1000 * 60 * 10);
```

in Chrome's javascript console.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){last_user_action = new Date().getTime();}, 1000)`

Comment: You can use `6e5` instead of `1000 * 60 * 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you are sure it works that way, you could use setInterval every minute to set the value:

```
setInterval(function(){
    last_user_action = new Date().getTime();
},60000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that directly, but it would be trivial to just update the variable periodically.

```
function updateLastUserAction() {
    last_user_action = new Date().getTime(); // or Date.now();
    setTimeout(updateLastUserAction, 10000); // run again in 10 seconds
}

updateLastUserAction();
```

You can change the update period to suit you - since the update function is extremely lightweight, you can run it pretty often and it won't matter.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming `last_user_action` is a global variable*, that means it's actually a property of `window` and you can define a getter for that property.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'last_user_action', {
  get: function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }
});
last_user_action; // 1412882205169
last_user_action; // 1412882206490
```

This would normally be a bad idea, but given you are hacking here, it doesn't seem so bad.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do that with a variable.

But you can do it with a property, using a getter:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'last_user_action', {
    get: function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
});
obj.last_user_action; // Current date time
```